# Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer contol add custom controls inside ToolBar

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms, reportviewer

Is there any way to I add my custom controls inside Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer contol.
I am developing ASP.NET web app and I want to add my custom controls inside toolBar of reportviewer.

Reading this [blogspot](http://devgig.blogspot.com/2009/05/extend-reportviewer-toolbar.html) it looks like that is possible in WinForms.

So I start coding my own RerpotViewerClass that inherits ReportViewer and I get stacked at start.
Looks like I can't override OnControlAdded method on WebForms ?
Shod I then use OnLoad() or any other ?

```
   public class ReportViewerToolbarExtension : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer
    {
        protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
        {

                base.OnControlAdded(e);

        }        
    }
```

Raisse error

```
'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'OnControlAdded'
```

Also  "ControlEventArgs" is misery part for me ?

When I try to implement SetToolStripItems(Control c)

I can't use  ToolStripItemCollection  also  Toolstrip becuse they are belong to namespace System.Windows.Forms.
Should I reference  WinForms or there are analog controls  inside Web namespace ?

Comment: you cant use the windows forms controls in the web form report. There is no easy way, please see my updated answer

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it is not possible to customize the web report viewer toolbar. By looking at the disassembled code you can see that the ToolbarControl used is a custom one and it is a internal sealed class and you can only hide or show the toolbar.

However it is possible for you to hide the toolbar and create your own that implements the same functionality as the existing one and your own controls.

This is the suggested route by Microsoft.

> If you want a different toolbar implementation, you can create a
>   custom toolbar to replace the default toolbar.

This is found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670.aspx

What I would do is disassemble the code and re-implement it again as a public class with all the child classes which from my first look don't seem to have anything too complicated or difficult to do.

Also it would be possible to add it through the front end by editing the DOM using tools like **jquery** or just the **DOM** api. The web developer post below demonstrates how you could do that. Please bear in mind the *implications* of that if you want server side controls to be added to the toolbar you will need to make sure you dont invalidate the view state and that they work correctly.

Please see the following post hosted on the asp.net forum for a similar question.

- [Customize Report Viewer Toolbar By adding WebControls to it](http://forums.asp.net/t/1563850.aspx/1)

Useful disassemble tools.

- [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) (Free)
- [Reflector.Net](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (Commercial)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="830px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Коллекция)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <div id="container" class=" " style="display: inline-block; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; vertical-align: top;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="28px">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ComboBox1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem>Option 1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Option 2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Option 3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $($('#ReportViewer1_fixedTable').find('td[colspan=3] div[id^="ReportViewer1"]')[1])
                    .find('div')
                    .first()
                    .append($('#container').detach());
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

When you using ExtJS or Ext.Net then replace script block with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.get(Ext.query('#ReportViewer1 td[colspan=3] div[id^="ReportViewer1"]')[1]).last().appendChild(Ext.get(Ext.query('#container')));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanx, DO I need to refernec jquery to my project ?

Comment: Yes, you need install jquery into your project. By default in web forms jQuery already exists. You can refresh it version using:
PM > install-package jQuery

Comment: May I be rough to Ask, Can this be done using  Ext.Net, Because My project already is referred to Ext.Net , And Ill more preferred to use Ext.Net libraries if it there is way. Thanx once again

Comment: Yes, I try to write example. Please wait

Comment: Great yes editing the DOM then anything is possible ;) good point